# unable to import gspread module despite being installed

Tags: python, gspread

I am unable to run gspread on my fabric script despite I have installed gspread via pip. what did i miss out?

```
Gangzhengs-MacBook-Pro:Fabric mosesliao$ pip install gspread
Collecting gspread
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests>=2.2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from gspread)
Installing collected packages: gspread
Successfully installed gspread-0.3.0
Gangzhengs-MacBook-Pro:Fabric mosesliao$ fab google_docs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fabric/main.py", line 658, in main
    docstring, callables, default = load_fabfile(fabfile)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fabric/main.py", line 165, in load_fabfile
    imported = importer(os.path.splitext(fabfile)[0])
  File "/Users/mosesliao/svn/chubi-trunk-project/Fabric/fabfile.py", line 29, in <module>
    import gspread
ImportError: No module named gspread
Gangzhengs-MacBook-Pro:Fabric mosesliao$ pip install gspread
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): gspread in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests>=2.2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from gspread)
Gangzhengs-MacBook-Pro:Fabric mosesliao$ python -V
Python 2.7.11
```

Answer (score 1):

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fabric/main.py", line 165, in load_fabfile
```

and

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): gspread in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

seems to indicate that there are two `python2.7` installations on your machine. One is "Mac-like" and the other one is "Linux-like". Maybe you are using the `python` from the Mac default installation and the `pip` from the other. At least it's worth a try...

```
which pip
which python
```

Comment: Gangzhengs-MacBook-Pro:Fabric mosesliao$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
Gangzhengs-MacBook-Pro:Fabric mosesliao$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python

Comment: both comes from /usr/local/bin

Comment: Try `python` from the console and then `ìmport sys` and `print sys.path`. Let's see whether your `gspread` is in the path...

Comment: I was thinking about `export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` (assuming you are using `bash`) before calling the python script. But isn't this `fab`. So it's doing some `ssh`. What is the deatination of that call?  Maybe you can post the source of `fabfile.py` (in the question!).